# SQL Query for many to many mapping

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables

```
Entries Table 

ID    Name      Title
1     test1     hello1
2     test2     hello2
3     test3     hello3


Keywords Table
ID    Text
5     sample
6     testing
7     hello

EntryKey Table
ID     KeywordID     EntryID
1         5             1
2         6             2
3         7             3
4         6             2
5         7             1
```

The entry and keywords have many to many relationship. Each entry can have multiple keywords and one keyword can be in more than one entries

What I want is to get the entries and its associated keywords but I dont want to repeat the entries in listing.

My attempt

```
 SELECT e.id, e.title, e.name, e.text, e.emailaddress, k.text
  FROM entries e
       LEFT JOIN keyentries ke
              ON e.id = ke.entryID
      LEFT JOIN keywords k
              ON k.id = ke.keywordID ;
```

but it gives me entry 1 and 2 twice because it has two keywords.
Any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT to get them all together.

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, e.name, e.text, e.emailaddress, GROUP_CONCAT(k.text) keywords
FROM entries e
LEFT JOIN keyentries ke
    ON e.id = ke.entryID
LEFT JOIN keywords k
    ON k.id = ke.keywordID
GROUP BY e.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it doing so:

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, e.name, e.text, e.emailaddress, k.text
FROM entries e
LEFT JOIN keyentries ke
    ON e.id = ke.entryID
LEFT JOIN keywords k
    ON k.id = ke.keywordID
GROUP BY e.id;
```

Comment: it gives me correct entries but each entries have multiple keywords I want to get all the words of an entry as well :)

Comment: Could you add in your question the result you expect, pls?